# What a "Bismarckian realist"

Tags: political-philosophy, continental-philosophy, realism

I know who Otto von Bismarck is, I understand how someone would qualify as a realist. I don't understand what a "Bismarckian realist" is. Could someone explain this concept to me in detail?

Comment: Can we have a source for that?

Comment: @iphigenie [Here](http://www.worldpoliticsreview.com/articles/13103/the-realist-prism-a-bismarckian-approach-to-solving-21st-century-conflicts) is my source.

Answer (score 4):

**Realism** is a term with thousands of definitions. In this case, this is political realism. The meaning is that politics is based on power -- ultimately physical might. This view is often called [Realpolitik.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realpolitik) Specifically, Bismarck engaged in several [measured trades](http://www.worldpoliticsreview.com/articles/13103/the-realist-prism-a-bismarckian-approach-to-solving-21st-century-conflicts) rather than imagining he could get everything at once.

Answer (score 0):

A "Bismarckian Realist" is a pragmatic and unidealistic approach towards politicking  and governing.

With regard to Bismarck himself, he is, in a way, Modern History's First real political pragmatist who had little interest in the loftiness of political idealism and rhetoric.